# Install packages during uck Ubuntu customization

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am following the steps from [this website](https://peteris.rocks/blog/customize-ubuntu-desktop-live-cd-usb/) to customize my Ubuntu image. After unpacking the clean .iso I add some files to the "remaster" and also I would like to install some apps (wireshark for example), so when the systems boots with the custom image, there is no need to install anything. I run the following script:

```
sudo uck-remaster-clean
sudo uck-remaster-unpack-iso my.iso
sudo uck-remaster-unpack-rootfs

// .. add desired files to the remaster
sudo apt-get install wireshark

sudo uck-remaster-pack-rootfs -c
sudo uck-remaster-pack-iso -g myNew.iso
```

However, wireshark is installed on the machine on which I am running the script, not in the remaster-root system. What do I need to modify to have the apps installed on the unpacked ISO? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped a step, you need to `sudo uck-remaster-chroot-rootfs` before.

> Now you can install packages with apt-get and perform all kinds of customizations.